# Does the salary of a PhD student at a German university meet the financial requirement for a German Student Visa?

Tags: phd, germany, salary, visa

This is a question for Nationals from Australia, Honduras, Israel, Japan, Canada, New Zealand, Republic of South Korea, United States of America who have successfully obtained their Student Visa/Residence Permit to do their Ph.D.s in Germany.

I keep seeing the requirement of a minimum amount of €10,236/year in a German blocked bank account/Sperrkonto for the Student Visa. I have learned that international Ph.D. students in Germany are required to first get the Student Visa then the Residence Permit. However, I am unclear if Ph.D. students are exempt from depositing €10,236 for each year of their studies in a German blocked bank account or if their salary will meet that requirement. This concerns me because the Ph.D. program I applied to in Germany is three years long and I am unclear if I am expected to deposit €10,236 x 3 at once.

I also applied to a Ph.D. program in Sweden and they only require me to show proof of salary from the university I have been accepted to so I'm wondering if it's the same for Germany.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you sure you need a student visa? In general you are a worker when doing a PhD, not a student. In any case visa issues should go to the expatriates SE.

Comment: Yes, Ph.D. students are to apply for a Type D National Visa, either before or after entering Germany. Once awarded the Visa, we are to apply for a Residence Permit. I will go to the Expat SE. Thank you!

Comment: Ask the visa issuer.

Comment: For the financial side, the salary should be enough. I am not sure but I would be astonished if not.

Comment: Just a comment as I never had to do this myself: my foreign fellow PhD students with visa had visas with the same expiry as their employment contracts as PhD student, so I expect such a contract is sufficient. PhD students get TVL 13 which is initially ≈ 28 k€/a net (after taxes and health insurance) for a full time position or ≈17 k€/a net for a half time position, so both sufficient. It's quite usual that the initial contract duration is only 2 years with the option to prolong unless the project goes seriously wrong.

Comment: If you get a schlarship, you'll have to pay health insurance yourself, so you need to figure that in. Expect around 17,5 % to go away for health insurance if you end up in the volountary obligatory (!) class of Governmental health insurance so a scholarship below 12.5 k€/a may not be sufficient. But there may be much cheaper health insurance options for you. Scholarships have 0 income tax.